# Will memoization work for all DP problems?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was solving this famous DP problem (ROD cutting) [Problem Link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rod-cutting0840/1#)

I understood the approach given in the editorials, but I came up with my own recursive solution..

that actually worked but the time limit is exceeding, so when I tried memoizing the same, I'm getting different answers

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Approach 1:
// Recursion
int helper1(vector<int> &price, int size, int index, int profit)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return profit;
    if (size < 0 or index == price.size())
        return INT_MIN;
    return max(helper1(price, size - (index + 1), index, profit + price[index]),
               helper1(price, size, index + 1, profit));
}

int cutRod1(vector<int> &price)
{
    int n = price.size();
    return helper1(price, n, 0, 0);
}

// Approach 2:
// Recursion + Memoization
int helper2(vector<int> &price, int size, int index, int profit, vector<vector<int>> &dp)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return profit;
    if (size < 0 or index == price.size())
        return INT_MIN;

    if (dp[index][size] != -1)
        return dp[index][size];

    return dp[index][size] = max(helper2(price, size - (index + 1), index, profit + price[index], dp),
                                 helper2(price, size, index + 1, profit, dp));
}

int cutRod2(vector<int> &price)
{
    int n = price.size();
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n + 1, vector<int>(n + 1, -1));

    return helper2(price, n, 0, 0, dp);
}

void solve()
{
    vector<int> price{3, 9, 13, 12, 8, 12, 8, 8, 3, 10, 13};

    cout << cutRod1(price) << endl;
    cout << cutRod2(price) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0);
    int t{1};
    // cin >> t;
    while (t--)
        solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Recursive solution's result: 49 (Correct)

Memoized solutions's result: 48 (Wrong)

Intuition behind my approach:

> It is an unbounded Knapsack problem, we have two choices:
>
> 1. Take a cut at index's position and stay there (for making furthur cuts at the same position)
> 2. Not take a cut at index's position, move to next index (index+1)

can anyone help me finding out the reason why memoized version doesn't work

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve] with a hard coded test case that gives different results? Instead of trying to do everything on one line why not invert your logic? `if (dp[index][size] == INT_MIN) dp[index][size] = ...; return dp[index][size];`

Comment: Please provide more details to elaborate `doesn't work`

Comment: I just did add my intuition and the testcase it didnt work for

Comment: I can't copy/paste/compile it, so it's not a [mcve]. You have a failing case, use a debugger.

Comment: @RetiredNinja now you can do copy/paste/compile it..

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `profit` in the memoization lookup. At some point, you're calling `helper` with the same (size, index) pair but the passed in profit value is different.

Comment: okay, now that i understand this issue, how do i improvise this solution and overcome this issue, any suggestion?

its easier if i go by the editorials but this has been running over my mind for an entire day now

just curious to know if there is a fix

Comment: @PremnaathVaradharajan It _might_ be enough to adjust the returned (and possibly cached) value by the difference in profit (so if the passed in profit is 1 higher than was passed in with the cached value was saved, increase the cached value by 1, update the associated saved profit value, and return the new cached value), but I don't know if that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with memoization. The source contains a complete explanation. [Source](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/the-rod-cutting-problem)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm> // To use the built in max function
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Suppose that we have a rod of length 5, and an array containing the 
  // length(1,2,3 and 4 ) and price(2,5,7 and 8 ) of the pieces.
  int price[] = {2,5,7,8};
  int n = 5;

  // Declaring a 2D array, T
  int T[n-1][n+1];

  // Initializing the array to all zeros
  for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < n+1; j++ )
    {
      T[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < n+1; j++ )
    {
      // First column => 0 length of rod => 0 profit
      if(j == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      // First row => T[i-1][j] doesn't exist so just pick the second value
      else if(i == 0) {
        T[i][j] = price[i] + T[i][j-i-1];
      }

      // where j <= i => T[i][j-i-1] doesn't exist so just pick the first value
      else if(j-i-1 < 0) {
        T[i][j] = T[i-1][j];
      }

      // using the whole expression
      else {
        T[i][j] = std::max(T[i-1][j], (price[i] + T[i][j-i-1]));
      }
    }
  }
  // Answer in the extreme bottom right cell
  cout << "Maximum profit is " << T[n-2][n] << endl;



  return 0;
}
```